# Conditional from recursion returning undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion, prototype, undefined

My code will keep looping until the length of the customerTimeArray is zero.

When I console.log before the return line it outputs 10, which is the correct answer.

```
function Supermarket() {
  this.customerTimeArray;
  this.currentTillers = [];
  this.runningTime = 0;
}

Supermarket.prototype.queueTime = function(customerTimeArray, numberOfTills) {
  this.customerTimeArray = customerTimeArray;
  if (customerTimeArray.length === 0) {
    return this.runningTime;
  }
  this.currentTillers = this.customerTimeArray.splice(0, numberOfTills);
  this.deductLowestToAll(this.currentTillers);
  this.queueTime(this.customerTimeArray, numberOfTills);
};

Supermarket.prototype.deductLowestToAll = function(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  var lowest = Math.min.apply(null, array);
  array.forEach(element => {
    newArray.push(element - lowest);
    if (element === lowest) {
      this.runningTime += lowest;
      newArray.pop(element);
    }
  });
  this.currentTillers = newArray;
};

supermarket = new Supermarket();
supermarket.queueTime([1, 2, 3, 4], 1);
```

Comment: It should be `return this.queueTime(this.customerTimeArray, numberOfTills);`

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Seemed to be caught in an infinite loop when I added this

Comment: Adding `return` statement obviously can't increase call stack :) So, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought you meant changing the other return, not adding return to the end of the queueTime function. Yeah this works, thanks.